# IsMouseOver trigger for BorderThickness is not working in XAML

Tags: wpf, triggers

I want to change button's thickness when cursor is on it. I tried to do it using this code:

```
<Button BorderThickness="1" Content="Düzenle" Height="20" Width="50" Foreground="Blue">
<Button.Style>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="4"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Button.Style>
</Button>
```

But this code is not working to trigger the changes. What is the method to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's a bit subtle, the 'focus style' is interfering with that,**

I've created a style using default `Button` one and added that line with Blend:

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
    ...
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="border" Value="5"/>
</Trigger>
```

[image]

**Complete code**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#FFDDDDDD"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFBEE6FD"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF3C7FB1"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFC4E5F6"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF2C628B"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF4F4F4"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFADB2B5"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF838383"/>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="border" Value="5"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Border}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" Margin="100" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Beware you need all these resources, not only the style, so it's probably better that you'd put that in a `ResourceDictionary` ;)

See this complete tutorial:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsldesigner/2010/06/03/creating-and-consuming-resource-dictionaries-in-wpf-and-silverlight/